# How to choose specific initializer when signatures are the same?

Tags: swift

I have an `Item` struct with 2 initializers:

1. `init()`, which sets default values inside the body.
2. `init(isAvailable:count:)`, which has default arguments.

```
struct Item {
    var isAvailable: Bool
    var count: Int

    init() {
        self.isAvailable = false
        self.count = 0
    }

    init(isAvailable: Bool = true, count: Int = 100) {
        self.isAvailable = isAvailable
        self.count = count
    }
}
```

This compiles fine. However, when I do...

```
let item = Item()
```

... how do I control which `init` is actually used?

Since there are no parameters being passed in, both initializers should be possible candidates. The first one, `init()`, obviously matches. The `init(isAvailable: Bool = true, count: Int = 100) {}` should also be fine, since the default arguments let me skip passing them in.

Swift seems to use the first `init() {}`:

```
let item = Item()
print(item) /// Item(isAvailable: false, count: 0)
```

However, is there a way I can choose to use the second initializer instead?

```
let item = Item-2() /// Something like this.
print(item) /// Item(isAvailable: true, count: 100)
```

I *could* pass in one of the parameters, resolving the ambiguity, but then I'd need to keep track of the default value elsewhere. I'd prefer not to do this.

```
let item = Item(isAvailable: true) /// must remember the default value is `true`
print(item) /// Item(isAvailable: true, count: 100)
```

How do I choose which initializer to use when their signatures match?

Comment: This design is kind of weird, don't you think? You normally wouldn't have two different and equally "default" sets of default values, one for each initialiser overload. Maybe it's just me but I can't think of a case where two initialisers like this would be useful - in most situations you'd just write one initialiser to provide the more "default" set of default values, and have the more "special" set of default values be provided with a named factory method.

Comment: @Sweeper yeah, I agree it's kind of weird. I just kind of wanted to know how Swift determines which initializer is chosen.

Comment: "The general principle is that the _most specific_ overload should win" - from Jordan Rose on the Swift forums [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/compiler-choosing-between-functions-with-no-parameters-vs-functions-with-default-parameters/23501/2). You can actually tell the compiler to choose `init(isAvailable:count:)` by adding the [`@_disfavoredOverload`](https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/disfavoredOverload/) attribute to the parameterless `init` – but this attribute is not officially supported yet, so it should be used with caution.

Comment: Another approach to having a second or multiple init methods is to use static factory methods imo, you also get the advantage that you can name them to something that fits their purpose.